# Start a docker service based on another service

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm

Is there a possibility to start a service on a specific node, based on another running service? (using Docker Swarm)

To make myself a little more clear:

I want to run Nextcloud on a different node than for example, a Typo3, to spare some resources on my Nextcloud node.

How would I write that in a compose?

Answer (score 1):

Look into [deploy](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#deploy) and using [labels](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#labels-1):

Example:

```
        deploy:
            mode: replicated
            replicas: 1
            placement:
                constraints:
                - node.labels.NextcloudDaemon == true
            restart_policy:
                condition: any
```

The above example will run exactly 1 container, and only on the node you've already given the label of "NextcloudDaemon".